# What is the best path for the monkey sub in bloons td 6?

Tags: bloons-td-6

I have played bloons td 6 for a while by now but I still can't figure out which path upgrade for the monkey sub is best. I know that path 1 makes it a support tower, path 2 makes it a strong offense tower, and path 3 makes it half offense and half defense. Does anyone know which upgrade is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bloontonium reactor is broken early game, first strike capability/premptive strike is great mid-late game, and bottom path is airburst darts and sub commander which is decent all around, its up to preference.